# Structure of an installer wizard

Tags: c#, architecture, configuration, installation

I'm working on an installation and configuration application in C# for a project I'm working on, and I'm wondering what the best method of internally organising everything is.

Requirements:

- Single executable for deployment, no other files bundled with it.
- Has to support custom config steps on each panel, which contribute to a generated XML config file at the end.
- Certain steps may be skipped based on certain choices made within the installer flow.
- Must support dynamic config screens based on information fed back from classes in one of my libraries.

Here's a description of my prototype:

- A large form with a bunch of Panel controls, each representing one "screen" of the wizard. Each is named appropriately.
- A class for each "screen", deriving from a base type I defined. I call specific methods of it (e.g. `Enter`, `Back`, `Forward`) when certain events occur.
- State is stored as a `Dictionary<string,object>`, which is passed to each screen. The final screen (the actual "Installing..." screen) reads config out of this and dumps it into the XML file.
- Each screen's code is responsible for handling the "Next" and "Prev" buttons, so I can control where it jumps to based on settings in the current screen.
- A number of modules are stored in my library which provide information about extra config steps that need to be taken. I'm implementing this through reflection and automated UI generation.
- Assets are stored in the resources of the executable.

I don't want to use a generic installer package (e.g. InstallShield) because the logic is totally custom and calls upon one of my class libraries. What I would like to know is - am I setting this out in a really circuitous way? Is there a simpler or more standard way to wizard-style applications?

Comment: InstallShield, WiX, NSIS - all these installers support calling out to custom libraries. They are also able to handle custom install steps and any crazy logic you might have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's the short answer:**

A commercial tool is perfect for what you need because it supports both custom installation UI and dynamic XML files. Anything else requires a lot of learning and hard work.

**And the long explanation:**

A custom installation UI is not an easy task. Windows Installer offers built-in dialogs and controls, so it's usually the best solution. You could also try a proprietary installation engine, but you will need to learn it.

You're also taking an incorrect approach by trying to control everything with custom code and classes. Most setup authoring tools offer direct support for handling the installation UI and XML files. Why try reinventing the wheel?

So you basically need to find the setup authoring tool which is best for you. Here is a general list:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

The tools are either MSI-based or proprietary. Personally I prefer Windows Installer (MSI packages).

Trying to implement all your tasks with custom code is just not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The only proper way to install software on Windows (which I assume is your target platform) is using [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688%28VS.85%29.aspx). Simplifying a bit Windows Installer is based on the concept of a installation package (a database file) that in a transactional way can be added or removed from the system.

If you write your own installation logic you will not be able to participate in the transactional handling of software installation. If your uninstaller gets deleted there is no way the user can uninstall your software. Also, Windows Installer knows A LOT about the quirks of Windows which you may not be aware of.

Windows Installer provides a somewhat [cryptic API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372860%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for creating packages but you can also use then open source [WiX toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) which is quite powerful or any commercial installer like [InstallShield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm).

If you decide to go the Windows Installer way you should try to avoid custom actions if possible. Custom actions suffer from the same "transaction rollback" problem as a custom installer. You create the code for the custom action rollback/uninstall say in a DLL and if that DLL is lost there is no way Windows Installer can undo your custom action.

Windows Installer is actually quite powerful. You havn't given any specific information about the "custom stuff" you need to do but perhaps Windows Installer already has a table for that?

Comment: The "custom stuff" is basically using reflection to list classes that derive from a specific base class in my library, then calling custom configuration steps on each. The user has to be presented with configuration questions (like how the Apache installer/configurator works) which are then used to produce a special config.xml file, which also contains some auto-generated (but different and random for each machine) scheduler timing info for certain jobs. The problem is that generic installers don't give me the ability to provide a truly custom UI, e.g. one step lists all installed services.

Comment: To me it sounds like you are trying to create a configuration tool and not an installer? If that is true I probably should delete my answer as it doesn't really apply.

Comment: It's both. The configuration needs to take place at installation time.

Answer (score 0):

Use InstallShield or the MSI installer. Seriously. In addition to being able to support all kinds of custom logic (including code you specify), the generic installer wizards do things you're not even thinking about, like, say, listing the installed app in Programs and Features, and performing repair installs/uninstalls.

With the level of custom logic you're looking at, I would fork out for the latest InstallShield installer builder; the VS Install project builds into a pretty simple dialog set.

EDIT: Fair enough, been in that position before.

I would still HIGHLY recommend using any generic installer tools you have available, like VS's Install project, for the reasons I stated above; the install packages do things you aren't even thinking about in your design, and you get all of it for free.

Instead of putting this logic to customize your XML config file in the installer, how about putting it in your executable, as a "run-once" configuration wizard that the user will see when they start the application after installing it? It shouldn't be too off-putting to your users, and it should work well if the actual application is also a WinForms app (even if it isn't; you could compile the configurator into a different app and have your main app launch the configurator if it doesn't have an XML file).

Comment: Unfortunately my budget is zero for this, and InstallShield (along with anything else that costs money) is prohibitively expensive by that standard.

Answer (score -1):

> Single executable for deployment, no other files bundled with it.

This might of some interest to you : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

Comment: Not what I wanted at all. I can easily bundle the DLLs inside the resources and ilmerge the lib into my installer project's binary - that's no problem. What I'm interested in is the actual architecture of the installer wizard, and how best to set it out.